# Why application throwing exception while starting progress dialog throw application

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here is the exception which I am getting while handler try start the Progress Dialog from application

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
 at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
```

Please suggest solution if anybody knows

Comment: Please paste the code where you create the ProgressDialog. It seems that you are passing NULL as the Context parameter.

Comment: Satya you should have shown your code too. anyway first guess is change Context to Activity.this instead getApplicationContext()

Comment: I have creates my Application class & in that created function startProgressDialog which gives this exception

Comment: thanks @Frankenstein it work by using  Activity.this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Your Context To `ActivityName.this`

Because this **[BadToken Exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.BadTokenException.html)** ,So In your case you are adding the Progress Dialog to Your Activity Screen but passing the wrong context.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you had paste your code. By the error logs its problem with your context. You might be passing a different context for the activity you are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

For progress dialog use context obtained by, below method

> getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

Would have been lot easier if you pasted your code... but still there can be 2 possible reasons.
1. Context of wrong Activity.
2. you said that you are launching by a handler, please check the handler is of same activity for which you are using context in order to launch the dialog.